# Activex Type Library Error: Access denied at global code

Tags: c#, activex

I have created an Activex type library using c# and registered it using regasm.

```
[ProgId("ActivexControl.DemoActivex")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[Guid("29FF9CCE-B34F-4BE1-8D10-D6C3215D99A2")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class DemoActivex
{
    WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
    string printHTML = string.Empty;
    public PrintingHelper()
    {
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public String SayHello()
    {
        return "hello";
    }
   }
```

Below is the code to access activex in html page

```
<object id="DemoActiveX" classid="clsid:29FF9CCE-B34F-4BE1-8D10-D6C3215D99A2" codebase="ActivexControl.cab">
</object>
<script type="text/javascript">
    try {
        debugger;
            var obj = document.DemoActiveX;
            if (obj) {
                alert(obj.SayHello());
            } else {
                alert("Object is not created!");
            }
        } catch (ex) {
            alert("Some error happens, error message is: " + ex.Description);
        }

</script>
```

Its working fine if I am using it with simple HTML file but got Error: Access denied at global level if tried to use it in web application hosted in IIS.

[Here is the error detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbLt3.png)

Comment: Quote the **exact** error message.  And of course there is no point in posting the html that does not reproduce the error.

Comment: Hi Hans, Please check this http://i.stack.imgur.com/dbLt3.png

Comment: I have the same problem